# How to add user details to Firestore DB after email verification in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication

I am trying to add users information like email, name etc. to Firestore DB but after email successful verification. How can I do it..?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should implement Firebase authentication to your app.

the flow should be something like this:

- on firebase console go under authentication tab and enable email authentication
- in your app request user to register/login with firebase authentication by email
- after succesfull authentication your user can now write on firebase db
- done

now you have to create a new user in the users "table" with a reference to the authentication user id (not mandatory but nice)